# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: jvm-crash

We run our set of tests in our own test tool (Java Based)..and random test fails.....we get the below JVM fail error......Please Help.....

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006a0d5422, pid=7560, tid=2052

JRE version: 7.0_06-b24
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.2-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [jvm.dll+0x25422]
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000000dc6800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000004e80000,0x0000000004f80000] [id=2052]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000000000a8

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000073ae26d28, RCX=0x0000000000100010, RDX=0x000000073ae26d28
RSP=0x0000000004f7faf8, RBP=0x0000000000e6a660, RSI=0x000000076a5831d4, RDI=0x000000073ae26d28
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000100010, R10=0x000000000000000c, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x000000076a5831f0, R13=0x0000000000000020, R14=0x000000076a583160, R15=0x0000000000000020
RIP=0x000000006a0d5422, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000004f7faf8)
0x0000000004f7faf8:   000000006a15df4b 000000076a583030
0x0000000004f7fb08:   0000000000e6a660 000000076a583024
0x0000000004f7fb18:   000000000000000a 000000073ae26d28
0x0000000004f7fb28:   000000006a1a03fa 0000000000000ee9
0x0000000004f7fb38:   000000006a179dc9 000000076a583208
```

Answer (score 5):

I know I'm a "bit" late, but thought i should share this, as I also encountered this problem with java8. 
In [this link](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml), they have explained the reason (not the root cause) and how to solve it temporarily, till oracle fixes it.

Comment: Any alternatives if we cannot disable UAC due to being non-admin user or a due to a system policy?